# How to plot selected data of a column in R using ifelse conditional statements

Tags: r, if-statement, ggplot2, bar-chart, subset

I have a data set of placements with two of the columns being `status` and `salary`. There are other columns too but my question is regarding plotting of these two particular columns.

[image]

I want to plot only that data from the `status` column which has the value "Placed" in the rows, using conditional statements in the `ggplot()` function itself. Is it possible to do so and how?

My code is

```
ggplot(data = pl_data, mapping = aes(if x = (pl_data$status = "Placed"), y = (pl_data$salary), y = 'N/A'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too many conditional statements inside of the `aes()` call will make your code inscrutable. I would amend your data frame or simply 'filter out' the extraneous rows.

Please note: you didn't specify what `geom_` you will be using. Though not particularly germane to your question, it will be helpful in getting the best response from contributors. Here is what I would suggest. It appears you only want to include a subset of rows from the `status` column (i.e., `status == "Placed"`). Therefore, why not `filter()` your data frame inside of the `ggplot()` call. Try this:

```
ggplot(data =
         filter(pl_data, status == "Placed"),  # retain only the rows in the "placed" category
       mapping = aes(x = ..., y = ...)) +
  geom_
```

Note: `filter()` is from the `dplyr` package. I omitted parts of the code but I think you get the general idea. In my opinion, try not to use conditional statements inside of the `aes()` call. It is messy.

---

As per your comment, suppose you want to subset your rows across any arbitrary number of sub-categories. Simply use `%in%` to select all applicable rows in the `status` vector (i.e., column). Try something like this:

```
ggplot(data =
         filter(pl_data, status %in% c("Placed", "Almost Placed", "Not Placed")),  # retain the rows in multiple categories
       mapping = aes(x = ..., y = ...)) +
  geom_
```

Comment: Thank you Tom. As for the geom, apologies for not mentioning it. I wanted basic bar graph so would geom_bar(). The reason I opted for if else was, suppose in a situation that there are multiple categories(three or more) instead of two(as the case here) and I wanted to plot selected few from those, say 5 categories out of possible 8. Would filter work in that scenario too?

Comment: I recommend grabbing the necessary rows using `filter(data, status %in% c(...))`. I updated my response accordingly. However, if your data requires a lot of cleaning up (i.e., renaming, data type conversions, etc.), then I recommend adjusting the values of the `status` column *before* you plot your data.

Comment: Thank you Tom for the update. Filter looks a much better option. However, would you happen to know how the syntax for if else would be in aes? Just wanted to know from syntax point and couldn't find that specific answer anywhere. Filter though seems a much cleaner and faster way for practical implementation.

Comment: You aren't finding the syntax because not many people would do it...

Comment: In agreement with @AdamSampson, I am hesitant to advise you on modifying variables inside of the `aes()` function. I suppose you would receive less frowns if you did something quick like this: `aes(x = factor(status))`. I would recommend modifying the original data frame for major recodes (i.e., multiple `ifelse()` calls). Put simply, get the data in the best shape possible before visualization. Too many ad hoc adjustments inside of the `ggplot()` function is messy. It is also difficult to recommend further code without a reproducible example.